# How to get the scroll height of the iframe tag in LWC component using the onload event

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript

How to get the scroll height of the iframe tag used in the LWC component on after load to adjust the height of the LWC component dynamically based on the scroll height of the iframe element/tag in the JavaScript controller.

[image][image]

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have just added the screenshots of the logic that I have tried so far.